# repaint method not calling paint method

Tags: java, swing

trying to create a rectangle using paint but repaint method's not calling paint method.

even tried replacing paint with paintComponent, but still not working.
So what changes to make to make it work.
is there a problem with calling repaint method in run.

is there a problem with the instance.

trying to create a rectangle using paint but repaint method's not calling paint method.

even tried replacing paint with paintComponent, but still not working.
So what changes to make to make it work.
is there a problem with calling repaint method in run.

is there a problem with the instance.

```
package src;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class main extends JFrame implements Runnable{

private final int Height = 480;
private final int Width = 640;
Thread gameloop; 

public static main instance = null;

private main(){

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(this.Width,this.Height);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static main getInstance(){

    if (instance == null){

        instance = new main();}
    return instance;
}

private void start(){

    gameloop = new Thread(this);
    gameloop.start();

}


@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setColor(g2d.getBackground());
    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, instance.Width, instance.Height);
    g2d.setColor(Color.red);
    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);

}


@Override
public void run() {

    Thread current = Thread.currentThread();
    while (gameloop == current){
        try{
            Thread.sleep(5);
        }

        catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        repaint();
    }

}



  public static void main(String[] args){

      main.getInstance();

      main.getInstance().start();
}
```

}

Comment: Follow the Java naming conventions: `ClassNames` start with capital letters, `variableNames` with lowercase. In the constructor of your `main` class (sic!) you are creating a **new** frame. Remove the line `JFrame frame = new JFrame()`, and change `frame` to `this` in the subsequent lines. The code is still horrible, though....

Comment: Do not call the method outside of the EDT.

Comment: Don't override `paint` of top level containers like `JFrame`, `JFrame` contains at least two other components which can interfere with the painting process

Comment: okay, got it. I was just following instruction given [here](https://sites.google.com/site/javagamescorner/home/the-main-class)..trying to learn basics of "game making"?! @Marco13

Comment: The linked site at least follows the naming conventions. Beyond that, it **could** be OK-ish as an introductory example, but still has some questionable patterns (e.g. making the main class a Singleton for no real purpose).

Comment: can you suggest a better site to learning basics related to game making @Marco13. I took a class in java in last semester. But i cant start making any thing on my own except of basic textbook examples . Thank you.

Comment: Recommendations for external resources are "off topic" here on stackoverflow. Again, the tutorial may be OK to get started (and I cannot recommend a better one without googling). Books like http://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/~ad/jg/ (and its newer version), are **somewhat out-dated** (aiming at Java 1.4), but still contain lots of valuable information for the specific topic of game programming. But you should **NOT** read such a book like a "tutorial". Only read it when you already know the basics of (more modern) Java, so that you can filter out the parts that are no longer state of the art.

Answer (score 0):

The original problem was that you created a new JFrame in your constructor and then made that visible, instead of using the `main` instance you just created, so nothing in your `main` class was actually being displayed in your app, just a blank JFrame that does nothing. Also your `run` loop made no sense.

However, your code has a **lot** of other problems, both in logic and style. I'd advise you to just refactor *everything*. Here's a cleaner version that also solves your problem.

```
package src;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public final class Main extends JFrame implements Runnable {
    private volatile boolean running;

    private Main(int width, int height) {
        setSize(width, height);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private void start() {
        running = true;
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    private void stop() {
        running = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(g2d.getBackground());
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g2d.setColor(Color.red);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(40);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main(640, 480).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't extend `JFrame` and don't override `paint` (but only `paintComponent`). The `running` flag must be `volatile`. But... better than the initial one, sure.

Comment: thank you for the insight. I was learning basic(sort of..) of making a game from here:[link](https://sites.google.com/site/javagamescorner/home/the-main-class), there it was written like that. I tried the code there and it didnt work for me. when i copied the exact code given ,it did what was suppose to happen(i.e a red rectangle in left corner). So what's the problem with that? thanks anyway .